# how to retrieve Foreign key column values in sql

Tags: sql-server

i have a table 'Group'
it has Group id (primary key),Group Name, Sensor ID(Foreign key), Units Id.
Units ID is a foreign key reference to Sensor table.

while,

select * from Group

gives me a answer of

Group Id,Group Name, Sensor Id,Units Id.

but i want to get corresponding Sensor Id's Sensorname and Units id's Units name  from the sensor table in Group table.

how can i get that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a join:

```
select * from Group
left join Sensors ON Group.SensorId = Sensors.Id
```